# Getting botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials especially when I using CronTab

Tags: python, amazon-s3, cron, raspbian, boto3

I understand we have couple of answers for this error.  However, my issue is different hence the question.

I am pushing audio files from a raspberry pi to AWS-S3 instance.  The upload works without any problem when I run the script manually.  However the same script when run through a crontab instance it throws up the above error.

My python code is as follows:

```
import boto3
import argparse
import os
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f","--filetoupload", required=True, help="file to upload")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())
file = os.path.basename(args['filetoupload'])
client=boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-south-1')
print("[INFO:] Uploading file to cloud")
client.upload_file(args['filetoupload'],'MyS3Bucket',file)
print("[INFO:] File upload completed successfully")
```

I am calling this python script in a bash script.

```
python /home/pi/s3upload.py --filetoupload /home/pi/upload/${FILENAME}.mp3
```

The mp3 file gets created and as said above, when I run it manually it runs without any trouble.

I checked for the `config` and `credentials` files within `.aws` folder.  As indicated in other responses in SO, they start with default and have the right credentials set up.

The complete error message is as follows:

```
[INFO:] Uploading file to cloud
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/s3upload.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.upload_file(args['filetoupload'],'MyS3Bucket',file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 110, in upload_file
    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 279, in upload_file
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 73, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 233, in result
    raise self._exception
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
script finished
```

Comment: When you run from crontab your `$HOME` is by default `/`. When looking for AWS credentials, the default location is `$HOME/.aws`, so it might not be finding them. You can try either changing the $HOME in your crontab call, or relocating your files to /.aws (not recommended).

Comment: @jeremycg Thank you. 1) I tried moving the python file into .aws folder and made changes to the path in the sh file..didn't work..2) .i have updated the export PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/.aws/ in both bashrc and profile....and 3) added cd /home/pi/.aws in my crontab with * * * * * as the timeline...none of them worked...I am sure I am missing something in setting the $HOME....can you provide an example pls

Comment: @jeremycg Thank you...I tried this but still getting the same error.

Comment: try `export HOME=/home/pi/` to your .sh script. You can also try printing your path and home vars to a file from the script to make sure you have them set as you expect.

Comment: @jeremycg  Thank you again....I just added echo $HOME inside the sh script as the second line in the script and it started uploading the files without a glitch.  I am sure there must be a reason, which I could not figure out yet.

Comment: I changed `export HOME=/home/pi/.aws` in my previous comment to `export HOME=/home/pi/` in that one, that would be my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when crontab runs a script, it sets the `$HOME` variable to be `/`.

AWS looks for its credentials in a location which resolves to `$HOME/.aws`.

So, you need to either move your .aws directory into the root dir, which is probably not a good idea, or redefine `$HOME` to point to the folder that contains your `.aws` directory.

The easiest way to do this, if you are running your python script from a shell script, is to add:

```
export /HOME=/home/pi/
```

To the start of your shell script.